# Error on creating ManyToMany Relationship with Doctrine and Symfony2: "Unknown property 'orphanRemoval'"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to set up a ManyToMany between two entities, but when trying to update my schema with the console tool I get the following error:

> [BadMethodCallException]
>   Unknown property 'orphanRemoval' on annotation 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany'.

My entities look like this:

```php
class Customer implements UserInterface
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\CustomerBundle\Entity\Newsletter", inversedBy="subscribers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_newsletter_subscriptions")
     */
    private $newsletterSubscriptions;

    //...
}
```

and the other one:

```php
class Newsletter
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer", mappedBy="newsletterSubscriptions")
     */
    private $subscribers;
}
```

I can't figure out where this property `orphanRemoval` comes from.

I'm running Symfony v2.0.16 with Doctrine ORM 2.2.3.

Comment: It's weird. Maybe you have "orphanRemoval" in different entity? (you can't use orphanRemoval with ManyToMany association). I suggest you to grep your entity directory: "grep orphanRemoval ENTITY_DIR"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I haven't configured "orphanRemoval" in any relationships. I've found the keyword "orphanRemoval" in generated Cache files in the annotations folder, but it has been generated for other OneToMany relationships. I've cleared the application cache, but the error is still present.

Comment: Try drop whole schema and create it again. If error still exists try remove these two fields (I mean "$newsletterSubscriptors" and "$subscribers") and then recreate db. Does the error still occur if you remove these fields?